# Nextjs - passing props as components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm new to React and NextJS, and I've simplified the code below.

- I'm trying to make something into a separate component, but that means I need to pass Components as props.
- The separate child component I've created is ModuleToggle.
- The reason I'm doing it like this is because I have dozens of pages which need a "SegmentedControl"/3-way toggle. The Full, Condensed, Video props will be different for each page

career_progression.tsx (Original working code that I started with)

```js
export default function CareerProgression() {
   
   // "SegmentedControl" is a 3-way toggle.
   // Depending on which one is selected, a different component is loaded.

   const renderComponent:any = () => {
      switch(section) {
         case 'video':
            return <Video />
         case 'condensed':
            return <Condensed />
         case 'full':
            return <Full />
      }
   }

   return (
      { renderComponent() } // This updates part of the page based on what user toggles

      {/* Using a prebuilt Mantine component */}
      <SegmentedControl
         value={section}
         onChange={(value: 'video' | 'condensed' | 'full') => setSection(value)}
         data={[
            { label: 'Video', value: 'video'}, 
            { label: 'Condensed Detail', value: 'condensed'}, 
            { label: 'Full Detail', value: 'full'}, 
         ]}
      />
   );
}

export function Full() {
   return ( <Text>Full</Text> );
}

export function Condensed() {
   return ( <Text>Condensed</Text> );
}

export function Video() {
   return ( <Text>Video</Text> );
}
```

New career_progression.tsx (new parent)

```js
export default function CareerProgression() {
   
   // "SegmentedControl" is a 3 way toggle.
   // Depending on which one is selected, a different component is loaded.

   // state to pass to child is declared here
   const [activeComponent, setActiveComponent] = useState(null);

   return (
      { activeComponent } // This is the what I am trying to get the child to update and display

   // This is my attempt at creating separate component:
   <ModuleToggle_withState video={<Video/>} condensed={<Condensed/>} full={<Full/>}
      setActiveComponent={setActiveComponent} />

   );
}

export function Full() {
   return ( <Text>Full</Text> );
}

export function Condensed() {
   return ( <Text>Condensed</Text> );
}

export function Video() {
   return ( <Text>Video</Text> );
}
```

ModuleToggle.tsx (child)

```js
import { Dispatch, useEffect } from 'react';

export function ModuleToggle_withState(Video:Component, Condensed:Component, 
   Full:Component, setActiveComponent:any) {

   // This is my attempt but I'm not sure exactly how to reference component props
   useEffect(() => {
      switch(section) {
         case 'video':
            setActiveComponent=Video
         case 'condensed':
            setActiveComponent=Condensed
         case 'full':
            setActiveComponent=Full
      }
   }, [section]);

   }
   return (
      <SegmentedControl
         value={section}
         onChange={(value: 'video' | 'condensed' | 'full') => setSection(value)}
         data={[
            { label: 'Video', value: 'video'}, 
            { label: 'Condensed Detail', value: 'condensed'}, 
            { label: 'Full Detail', value: 'full'}, 
         ]}
      />
   );
}
```